# Print only on one side

Tags: header-footer

I am a new latex user and I have wrote a thesis.

How can update this code for print only on one side:

```
\pagestyle{fancyplain} \textheight22.5cm \topmargin0cm \textwidth16.5cm \oddsidemargin0.5cm \evensidemargin-0.5cm%
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{{$\color{IndianRed3}\blacksquare$} \hspace{0.1cm} \thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{{$\color{IndianRed3}\blacksquare$} \hspace{0.1cm} \thepage}}
```

Actual setting:
[image]

I want this result
[image]

Comment: Which document class do you use with which options?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,english,fleqn,openany,letterpaper,pagesize]{scrbook}

Comment: Sorry I am a new user. Can you write the new document class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
 ,fontsize=12pt
 ,english
 ,fleqn
 ,paper=letter % letter a4
 ,pagesize
 ,oneside  % <==========================================================
]{scrbook} % scrbook scrreprt scrartcl

\usepackage{blindtext} % to create dummy document or text ==============
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % caused a warning. Please read it!

\title{Test}
\author{username}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Compile it and check the result.  Option `oneside` advices KOMA-Script to print only one sided.  Then please comment line 7 out (marked with `<=====`) and compile once again. Compare the new result with the first one.

BTW: With KOMA-Script you should better use package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of your used package `fancyhdr`.

(Please create such an MWE next time by your own for your next questions. Thanks!)